# Remove first n elements from collection on Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, collections

I have collection of a models.
I need remove first n elements from the collection.

I know, how get first n elements (.first(n)), but I can't remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use shift:

```
while (n-- > 0) {
    collection.shift();
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the collection to the models after index n:

```
collection.reset(collection.slice(n));
```

Comment: It's better to use `remove` instead of `reset`, `collection.remove(collection.slice(n,collection.lenght))`

Comment: @KiTO for bulk operations, Backbone suggests reset. But I would assume that either one of us is right depending on the scenario, for instance depending on how much repainting bulk remove or reset would cause. Re: slice, it's definitely a function, you can find it in Backbone's source, can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Backbone reset save all current models in previusModels and add new models silently and after that trigger one event (reset), remove trigger an event for every remove (except when passed silent option) but it removes model and all related preferences.